# Cannot build Android tutorial project

Tags: android

I decided to learn a bit about programming for Android, so I started following the tutorial in the developer.android.com page. I installed Android Studio, created a project following the exact steps detailed here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html and when I try to build it I get the following errors

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

I cannot get past this error, googling about the error some suggested to change the SDK version but to no avail. With SDK Manager i have installed the build tools with revision 22.0.1, 23 and 24.3.4

EDIT: Here is the build.gradle file http://pastebin.com/X7635w6G

Comment: open the build.gradle of your module and check the version used for compilation, build tools and your targetSdk version

Comment: Delete the theme files that creates this error, And change the theme of your app to deviceDefault in 'AndroidManifest'

Comment: I posted the gradle in pastebin, they're all in 22 or 23

Comment: Where are those theme files? The file that's giving the error is values-v23/values-v23.xml but if I edit it and remove the error lines it's generated again

Comment: if they are in 22 or 23 then make every thing to 23 and don't remove those file bcoz they are generated by android from appcompat lib even if you remove them..they will be regenerated in the app-->build-->intermediate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change compile sdk to 23 into your build.gradle

from `compileSdkVersion 22`
to `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: Tried that, but I get this Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: : C:\Users\Daikon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: @Daikon, Is your project has one or more modules?

Comment: @Daikon,plese update your question with your actual build.gradle.

Comment: It seems that I had installed the build tools for 23, but not the actual SDK. Adding it in the SDK manager and then switching the compile version did the trick. Thanks for the help!